# Slick slider options change

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'd like to know if there is any way to pass new options to already created Slick carousel?
I have this code:

```
$('.bottom-slider').slick({
  asNavFor: '.top-slider',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  variableWidth: true,
  centerMode: true,
  etc...
});
```

and at some moment (added CSS class to restyle slider) I'd like to pass `slidesToShow: 5` to carousel. I tried with

```
$('.bottom-slider').slick({slidesToShow: 5});
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible? I prefer not to destroy/run again slider or create second box with "restyled" carousel.

Answer (score 20):

I found the description of `slickSetOption` on the [website](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to be a bit confusing, so leaving a couple examples here.

Set single option without UI refresh:

```
$('.initialized-carousel').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', 3);
```

Set multiple options with UI refresh:

```
$('.initialized-carousel').slick('slickSetOption', {
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1
}, true);
```

Comment: this doesnt seem working for rows property. 
eg: 

$('.exad-testimonial-carousel-wrapper').slick('slickSetOption', { 
    rows: 2,
}, true);

Answer (score 3):

Slick slider provides `slickSetOption` method to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably This will surely help you. you have to do it using  `slickSetOption` method with the help of jQuery. Paste this query in your custom JS file.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function () {
  jQuery('.bottom-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', 5);
});
```